# The specified method is not supported

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm working on a program that shows in a chart in asp.net two columns of a table, so I made a connection to my database (which is correct), the problem is in the metudo (Chart1.DataBindTable) that does not Is working And gives the following error: The specified method is not supported.

I was very grateful if anyone helped me.

The code:

```
         string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CS"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Consumo_Medio_Real], [Tipo_de_Fatura]  FROM [dbo].[t_faturas] GO", con);
            con.Open();

            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            Chart1.DataBindTable(rdr, " Consumo_Medio_Real");
```

Comment: Should there be a semicolon at the end of the select statement and before the GO command?

Comment: I would just remove the GO

Comment: GO is NOT a t-sql statement. It is the default batch separator in SSMS. The way you have this coded is that you have given the table t_faturas and alias of GO. :D

Comment: thanks but thats not, the error the error is in the DataBindTable!

Comment: `DataBindTable(…)` expects a list of `IEnumerable`, but IIRC `SqlDataReader` doesn't implement `IEnumerable`

Comment: @stuartd thanks but,
can you explain me better?

Comment: Correct, it doesn't implement IEnumerable. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader(v=vs.110).aspx . OP will need to read each line and insert it into a collection which implements IEnumerable.

Comment: You should also look closely at your field name. In your code you have a leading space.

Comment: thanks i correted it but stil is not the error @Sean Lange

Comment: You mean not the only error. :)

Comment: yes , true 
Can you suggest something else? @SeanLange

Answer (score 3):

Remove that `GO` from your SQL statement. Your SQL statement should looks like

```
SELECT [Consumo_Medio_Real], [Tipo_de_Fatura]  FROM [dbo].[t_faturas]
```

Well you are getting error cause the specified column name has space in it as can be seen below

```
Chart1.DataBindTable(rdr, " Consumo_Medio_Real");
                           ^... Here
```

It should rather be like below cause the column name represents the `X-Axis`

```
Chart1.DataBindTable(rdr, "Consumo_Medio_Real");
```

See below MSDN link for an example

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456766.aspx

Comment: thanks but thats not, the error the error is in the DataBindTable!

Comment: well seen but stil didn´t help @ Rahul

Comment: Can you suggest something else? @Rahul

Answer (score 0):

Try **without "GO"**

```
 string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CS"].ConnectionString;
 using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
 {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Consumo_Medio_Real], [Tipo_de_Fatura]  FROM [dbo].[t_faturas]", con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        //Add datatable...
        System.Data.DataTable dt  = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(rdr);
        var enumerableTable = (dt as System.ComponentModel.IListSource).GetList();
        chart1.DataBindTable(enumerableTable , "X");
```

And try dumping the data into some objet that implement ienumerable... and pass that as the parameter to .DataBindTable()

look the definition [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd455374%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)  (the SqlDataReader does not implement IEnumerable)

hope this help!

Comment: thanks but thats not, the error the error is in the DataBindTable!

Comment: try use dataset or datatable to pass into DataBindTable parameter

Comment: Nope that's not the issue at all. See my answer

Comment: [here](http://codedisplay.com/how-to-convert-sqldatareader-or-datareader-to-dataset-in-asp-net-c-vb-net/) you got an example...

Comment: @M56 add the dataset and the datatable but a had other error : Error 6 'DataTable' is an ambiguous reference between 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.DataTable' and 'System.Data.DataTable'

Comment: @DiogoGomes look at the code, i edited. Add a datatable and enumerable to get results before call DataBindTable...

Comment: when use the type "datatable" use complete reference... "System.Data.DataTable"...